# Existence of an antiderivative for a continuous function on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on a set $I\subset \mathbb{R}$. Does there always exist a function $F$ differentiable on an **open** set $J$ containing $I$ such that $F'=f$ on $I$ ?

The case where J is an interval has been studied in this thread [Existence of antiderivative on a part $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853497/existence-of-antiderivative-on-a-part-i-of-mathbbr)

Comment: Almost a direct repost of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853497/existence-of-antiderivative-on-a-part-i-of-mathbbr) last hour.

Comment: but now J is an open set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: There exists a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is continuous at each irrational, and discontinuous at each rational. Let $I$ be the irrationals. So we have $f$ continuous on $I.$ Show that if there were such an $F$ on an open $J$ containing $I,$ then $F'$ would violate the Darboux property on each connected component of $J.$

**Added later:** Here is such a function: Set $g(x) = 0$ for $x<0,$ $g(x) = 1$ for $x\ge 0.$ Let $r_1,r_2,\dots$ be the rationals. For $x\in \mathbb R ,$ define

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{g(x-r_n)}{2^n}.$$

Comment: the function that you think is the  Thomae's function? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_de_Thomae

Comment: No, not all. Thomae function is $0$ on the irrationals.

Comment: @Tina I added to my answer.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @zhw. Ugh, you are right. Differentiable, not continuously differentiable. Sorry.

Comment: @zhw please can you explain to me why If I is an interval of J, then F '(I) can not be  an interval

Comment: $f$ is an increasing function and hence its discontinuities are jump discontinuities; in particular, $f$ misses uncountably many values on each jump. Moreover, notice that any open interval on $J$ contains discontinuities of $f$. On the other hand, $F'$ coincides with $f$ except on $\Bbb Q$, a countable set.

Comment: @ Fimpellizieri thank's

Comment: I  asked a new question with  another definition of antiderivative function https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855483/antiderivative-function/2855485#2855485