# Correct definition of antiderivative function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the correct definition of antiderivative  function  on a set $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ (think of the case where $I = \mathbb{R}  / \mathbb{Q}$ )

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  and a set $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ (**edit**  $f$ is supposed to be defined on $ \mathbb{R}$ or on an open set containing $I$)

definition 1: an antidérivative  function   of $f$ on $I$ is a function $F$ differentiable on an open $J$ containing $I$ such that $F '= f$ on $I$

definition 2: an antidérivative  function   of $f $ on $I$ is a function $F$ (**edit**  $F$ is supposed to be defined on $ \mathbb{R}$ or on an open set containing $I$) differentiable on all points of  $I$ such that $F '= f$ on $I$

definition 3:  may be

Comment: What do you want to use this definition for? Usually, derivatives are only defined on open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268914/why-does-the-condition-of-a-function-being-differentiable-always-require-an-open

Comment: @Sambo i want to know if  $f$ is a continuous function on a set $I\subset \mathbb{R}$. Does there always exist an antideravative of f  ? with definition 1 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853575/existence-of-an-antiderivative-for-a-continuous-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset

Comment: Definitions are made up, and choosing a good definition depends on what it's used for. As you found out in the post you linked, definition 1 leads to a negative answer to your question. As for definition 2, you'll need to define what it means for $F$ to have a derivative at all points of $I$. For example, how would you define the derivative of a function on $I=\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Why do you want to know whether a function always has an antiderivative? In any context I can think of, we don't need to define on antiderivative on anything other than an open set.

Comment: of course , f is supposed to be defined on $\mathbb{R} $ or on an open containing I. Derivability in 1,2,3 is well known. what your choice 1 or 2

Comment: I meant differentiability of $F$. Is $F$ supposed to be defined outside of $I$ as well?

Comment: yes , I edited définition 1

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Part One): Let $f:I\to \Bbb R$ be continuous where $I$ is  a non-empty open interval. Let $a\in I.$ For all $x\in I$ we have:  $F(x)=\int_a^xf(y)dy$ exists  and $\frac {dF(x)}{dx}=f(x).$... Part Two (with $I$ and $f$ as in Part One) is that if $G'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ then for any $a \in I$ there exists $K_a\in \Bbb R$ such that $G(x)=K_a+\int_a^x f(y)dy$ for all $x\in I.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$%$
Personally, I would say that definition 2 makes more sense; that is:

> If we have functions $f,F: \R \rightarrow \R$ and a set $I \subset \R$, then we say $F$ is **an antiderivative of $f$ on $I$** if $F$ is differentiable on $I$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \in I$.

I don't see a reason why we should require $F$ to be differentiable on open sets around $I$. However, this requirement may be useful for applications of this definition, of which I know none. As I pointed out in a comment, it really depends on how one plans to use this definition.

Comment: @ SamboThank's. Are you ok with: If we have functions f,F :$D\subset R→R$ definded on open set D  and a set I⊂D, then we say F is an antiderivative of f on I if F is differentiable on I and F′(x)=f(x) for every x∈I.

Comment: Yes, that would also be reasonable.

Comment: Thank's , I will ask a new question with this definition https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855483/antiderivative-function/2855485#2855485