# Existence of an antiderivative function on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be  continuous at $x$ for every $x\in I$  where $I\subset \mathbb R$ could be arbitrary. Does there always exist a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable on $I$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x \in I$?

The definition of a primitive is naturally defined on an interval. A mathematical curiosity is to understand the difficulties that can be encountered when trying to define this notion on any part of $\mathbb{R}$.

A first difficulty is to try to find a good definition of the notion of a primitive on any part of $\mathbb{R}$. That was the purpose of this thread
"[Correct definition of antiderivative function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854891/correct-definition-of-antiderivative-function/2855112#2855112)."

If we ask $F$ to be differentiable on an open set $J$ containing $I$, the thread "[Existence of an antiderivative for a continuous function on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853575/existence-of-an-antiderivative-for-a-continuous-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset)" gives a counterexample to the question.

If $I$ is an interval, the answer to the question is positive.  If $I$ is an open set, the answer to the question is also positive. (see comment)

Comment: I suspect what you meant was "Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at everu point of a set $I\subset \mathbb{R}$." Saying that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is "a continuous function on $I$" is at best problematic, because "function on $I$" sounds like the domain is $I$. Also note that saying "continuous at every point of $I$" is stronger than saying "$f|_I$ is continuous", which is how one might interpret "continuous on $I$".

Comment: An example to illustrate the sort of problem I have with the way you phrased it, in case it's not clear: Say $f(t)=1$ for rational $t$, $f(t)=0$ for irrational $t$. _Is_ it correct to say "$f$ is continuous on $\Bbb Q$"? Probably no, since $f$ is continuous nowhere. **But** one might say yes, since $f|_{\Bbb Q}$ is continuous...

Comment: Perhaps the first sentence should be "Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},$ let $I\subset \mathbb R,$ and assume $f$ is continuous at each point of $I.$

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  Yes I edited my question

Comment: Somewhat related: [this](https://www.math.wvu.edu/~kcies/Presentations/C0vsC1vsC1&Peano_June2012v2short.pdf) and [this](http://www.auburn.edu/~brownj4/restthm.pdf)

Comment: @Tina I see that you have put a lot of effort into improving this question.  Thank you.  This is a nice question now.

Comment: The question is now posted on MathOverflow: [Existence of an antiderivative function on an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/306472#306502).

Comment: It took me a while to realize that $I$ is not an arbitrary *interval*, since $I$ is so often used for an interval. Maybe next time use a different symbol?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please do not upvote this answer! It's just a detailed version of an answer that appeared on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306472/existence-of-an-antiderivative-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbbr/306502#306502); if you feel the need to upvote something please upvote that answer instead.
$\newcommand\ui[2]{\overline{\int_{#1}^{#2}}}$

The obvious thing to try is $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt.$$Except "trying" that is stupid, since it's clear the integral need not exist. I thought about replacing $f$ by some nicer function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ if $f$ is continuous at $x$, as in a comment to the question on MO; couldn't make that work. The lightbulb Pietor Majer had is this: Use the [upper Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Darboux_integrals), which we will denote $$\ui ab f(x)\,dx.$$

The beauty of this is that if $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is any function whatever then $\ui ab f$ exists, at least as an element of $[-\infty,\infty]$, and if $f$ is any bounded function then $\ui ab f\in\Bbb R$.

Of course the upper Darboux integral probably doesn't really deserve to be called an *integral*, since it's not linear. But it does retain a shred of linearity:

> > **Lemma.** If $a<b<c$ and $f:[a,c]\to\Bbb R$ is bounded then $\ui acf=\ui ab f+\ui bc f$.

Proof: Exercise. Easy or not, depending on who you are. If you get stuck you should be able to extract a proof from a proof that $\int_a^c=\int_a^b+\int_b^c$ for the Riemann integral. Note that of course you need to find a proof in a context where the author defined the RIemann integral in terms  of "upper and lower (Darboux) sums" instead of using Riemann sums. I *suspect* the proof in baby Rudin will qualify, not sure since I don't have a copy.

It follows that the upper Darboux integral satisfies a version of FTC sufficient for our purposes:

> > **Lemma (UDI-FTC).** Suppose $f:(a.b)\to\Bbb R$ is bounded and $p\in(a,b)$. Define $F:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ by $F(x)=\ui pxf(t)\,dt$ (with the convention that $\ui\beta\alpha=-\ui\alpha\beta$). If $f$ is continuous at $x\in(a,b)$ then $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Proof: **Hint:** The previous lemma shows that $$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}
=\frac1h\ui x{x+h}f(t)\,dt;$$if $h$ is small then $f(t)$ is close to $f(x)$ on $[x,x+h]$ (or $[x+h,x]$, whichever makes sense).

If that's not enough note that $F'(x)=f(x)$ is explained in somewhat more detail in the answer on MO.

Of course it's  not clear how that helps, since $f$ is not bounded. But it's clear that $f$ is "locally bounded" on a neighborhood of $I$, and that that's enough. (This is the part where I'm adding details to the answer on MO, if anyone was wondering; at least one other person and I were both initially confused about this.)

> > **Definition** If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $S\subset \Bbb R$ then $f$ is *locally bounded on $S$* if for every $x\in S$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.
> >
> > **Triviality** If $f$ is locally bounded on $S$ and $K\subset S$ is compact then $f$ is bounded on $K$.
> >
> > **Corollary (UDI-FTC v2)** The UDI-FTC above holds if we assume just that $f$ is locally bounded on $(a,b)$.

Proof: Given $x\in(a,b)$, choose $c,d$ with $a<c<d<b$ and $x,p\in(c,d)$. Since $f$ is bounded on $[c,d]$ the definition of $F(s)$ makes sense for $s\in(c,d)$, and the proof of the original UDI-FTC shows that $F'(x)=f(x)$.

And now we're in business:

> > **Theorem.** Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $I\subset \Bbb R$, and $f$ is continuous at $x$ for every $x\in I$. There exists $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in I$.

Proof. If $x\in I$ there exists an open interval $I_x$ such that $x\in I_x$ and $f$ is bounded on $I_x$. Let $$V=\bigcup_{x\in I}I_x.$$So $V$ is open, $I\subset V$, and $f$ is locally bounded on $V$.

Say $V=\bigcup_kJ_k$, where the $J_k$ are the connected components of $V$. UID-FTC v2 above shows that for each $k$ there exists $F_k:J_k\to\Bbb R$ such that $$F_k'(x)=f(x)\quad(x\in I\cap J_k).$$Define $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $$F(x)=\begin{cases}F_k(x),&(x\in J_k),
\\0,&(x\notin V).\end{cases}$$

Comment: I do not see clearly why with your F, we have $F '(x) = f (x)\,  \forall x\in I$. I see clearly $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}, \forall x\in J_k,\ F(x)=F_k(x)$ and  since the $J_k$  are open intervals we deduce that $\forall k\in \mathbb{N},\, \forall x\in J_k,\ F'(x)=F'_k(x)=f(x)$. 
Now  note that $I\subset V=\bigcup_kJ_k$, thus 
 $\forall x\in I\,\,    \exists k\in  \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in J_k$ and $F(x)=F_k(x)$ but $I$ is not an interval "If $F(x)=F_k(x)$ holds only at isolated points, then nothing can be said about the , derivatives"

Comment: @Tina I don't follow your question too well, because some of it is answered by things you say. Anyway, suppose $x\in I$. There exists $k$ so $x\in J_k$. Now $J_k$ is _open_ and $F(t)=F_k(t)$ for all $t\in J_k$, so $F'(x)=F_k'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @Tina $F=F_k$ does not hold only at isolated points, it holds on all of $J_k$. $I$ is not an interval but $J_k$ _is_ an interval.

Comment: Show me clearly that $F '(x) = f (x)\,  \forall x\in I$ in case $I=\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Tina Whether $I=\Bbb N$ or not does not affect the argument. This part wasn't spelled out explcitly in the answer because it's obvious. Tell me what part you don't follow: (i) Suppose $x\in I$. (ii) There exists $k$ so $x\in J_k$. (iii) $F=F_k$ everywhere on $J_k$. (iv) $J_k$ is open. (v) Hence $F'(x)=F_k'(x)=f(x)$. You ask me to show you this clearly, but you don't say what was unclear about my previous comment.

Comment: I was lost for nothing we have $F'(x)=F_k'(x)=f(x)\quad  \forall  k, \forall x\in J_k $ thus  $F'(x)=f(x)\quad  \forall x\in \bigcup_kJ_k  =V$ In particular since $V\supset I$ we have $F'(x)=f(x)\quad  \forall x\in I$

Comment: Are you okey or no?

Comment: No, it's not true that $F_k'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in J_k$. That holds for all $x\in I\cap J_k$. (Similarly, not true that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in V$.)

Comment: I'll see that tomorrow thank's

Comment: I musn't do mathematics  after midnight. everything is back in order. Thank's.

Comment: Can we just upvote both? If you feel that you don't deserve reputation, then why not make it community wiki?

Answer (score 4):

A few comments: If the answer is yes I have no idea how to prove it.

**Edit:** Maybe it's  not hopeless. Given $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ the set of $x$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x$ is a $G_\delta$. So we can assume that $I$ is a $G_\delta$. It's certainly true if $I$ is open, so perhaps...

Of course the answer would be no if you asked for $F$ to be differentiable on  $\Bbb R$, for example $I=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, $f(t)=-1$ for $t<0$, $f(t)=1$ for $t>0$.

Otoh if the answer is no a counterexample can't be very simple. Because the answer is yes if $I$ is closed (in that case there exists $g\in C(\Bbb R)$ which agrees with $f$ on $I$), and the answer is yes if $f$ is locally Lebesgue integrable, in which case the indefinite integral works.

Comment: What if $f$ is locally in $L^1$ and $m(I) = 0?$

Comment: @zhw. I don't see what $m(I)$ has to do with it. If $f$ is locally integrable we can define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, and it follows that $F'=f$ at every point where $f$ is continuous, in particular at every point of $I$.

Comment: It works also if f is Riemann integrable (example f strictly monotone)

Comment: @Tina Well of course. That's actually included in what I said - if $f$ is Riemannn integrable then it's locally Lebesgue integrable...

Comment: If we ask that F be differentiable on an open, zhw has already given a counter example

Comment: @Tina A counterexample in one of those other threads? I imagine it's a counterexample to this: "Let $f$ and $I$ be above. Does there exist $F$ differentiable on an open set such that $f'=f$ on $I$?" A counterexample to _that_ does not contradict the fact that the answer to your question is yes if $I$ is open...

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich I only commented "Of course the answer would be no if you asked for F to be differetiable on R"

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, my question wasn't a very good one.

Comment: @Tina Oh - never mind.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  If I is an open set , we know that every open set of R is a countable union of disjoint open intervals , so f admits antidérivative function in each interval  then we can gives F no?

Comment: @Tina Right. Since you're not requiring that $F$ be globally continuous or anything we can just piece together the $F$'s for each interval.

Comment: @Tina Heh. I don't think you should really "accept" this answer, since it really doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  They voted that my question is off-topic. I had no choice. For  those who voted against: If one of you is a teacher and a student asks you the question "Sir, why are we looking for a primitive always on an interval" what is your answer

Comment: @Tina In case you missed it, the question has come back from the dead.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich  I just noticed it. 
thank's to the one who saved the question

Comment: To follow also on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306472/existence-of-an-antiderivative-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbbr