# Does every continuous function has an antiderivative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $A\subseteq A'$ and let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, does $f$ have an antiderivative? In my textbook the case when $A$ is an interval is proven, but I wonder if it is true for an arbitrary set. $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$, in my textbook the definition of antiderivative is given as follows:

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $A\subseteq A'$ and let $f, F: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions, we say that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ if $F$ is differentiable and $F'=f$.

When $A=[a, b]$ is an interval, the theorem is proved by simply taking
$$ F(x) = \int_a ^x f(t)dt.$$
This does not work for general $A$.

Comment: What is $A'$?  What is your *definition* of an "antiderivative"?

Comment: Forgive me for correcting the grammar, but it's "have" not "has."

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855483/existence-of-an-antiderivative-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbbr). But I think this is different; here $f$ and $F$ are defined only on $A$; there $f$ and $F$ are defined everywhere and continuous at each point of $A$.